# Nanopb - decode with PHP

Tags: php, c, protocol-buffers, nanopb

I have a message encoded with Nanopb implementation of Google Protocol Buffers.

I have to decode it to display the decoded result on a php page.

Is it possible to do it with PHP ?
If not, what is the best solution to do it in order to get an exploitable result in php ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you done any research? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protocol_Buffers#Language_support states *Third-party implementations are also available for PHP*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use php implementation of google protocol buffers like for instance:

[google/protobuf/php](https://github.com/google/protobuf/tree/master/php)

[protobuf-php](https://github.com/protobuf-php/protobuf)